# Exibir dados da tabela com chave primaria na tabela que tem a chave estrangeira - SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Criei em meu banco duas tabelas: PRODUTO e FORNECEDOR.
Na tabela FORNECEDOR há um campo CNPJ que é uma chave primaria.
Na tabela PRODUTO há uma chave estrangeira `FK_PRODUTO` que é interligada com o campo de CNPJ da tabela FORNECEDOR.

Estou fazendo a consulta da tabela PRODUTO usando `SELECT * FROM PRODUTO;` mas os dados da coluna `CNPJ_FORNECEDOR` que deveriam ser trazidos da tabela FORNECEDOR aparecem como `NULL`.

Código de criação das tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE FORNECEDOR
(
    CNPJ BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    RAZAO_SOCIAL VARCHAR(50),
    ENDERECO VARCHAR(50),
    CIDADE VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUTO
(
    CODIGO INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRICAO VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    ESTOQUE INT,
    VALOR INT,
    CNPJ_FORNECEDOR BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUTO FOREIGN KEY(CNPJ_FORNECEDOR)
    REFERENCES FORNECEDOR (CNPJ)
);
```

Comment: Não , não deveriam , os valores de CNPJ precisam serem inseridos na table PRODUTO.

Comment: @Motta, não existe nenhuma forma de trazer esses dados sem necessariamente inseri-los nas duas tabelas?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: *"mas os dados da coluna CNPJ_FORNECEDOR"* se estão null é pq foram inseridos como nul, é um problema dos dados e não da query. Ou seja, quando inseriu o produto, não "ligou" a nenhum cnpj de fornecedor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisamos entender alguns pontos primeiro. Se temos um produto relacionado á um fornecedor, em teoria, não podemos cadastrar um produto sem um fornecedor, ou seja, uma relação bem amarradinha, o sgbd nem deixaria cadastrar um produto com o campo cnpj_fornecedor vazio ou com um cpnj no qual ainda nenhum fornecedor fora cadastrado ainda. Resumindo, Vc só poderia cadastrar um produto com um cnpj que ja existisse na tabela de fornecedores. Em suma, um produto que não possui um fornecedor, é produto que surgiu do além, pois mesmo que fosse criado por sí mesmo, ele deveria ter você mesmo como fornecedor.
Levando essa informação em conta, então cnpj_fornecedor deveria ser "not null". assim obrigando a existência de um fornecedor e evitando produtos sem origem com cnpj_fornecedor null por exemplo.

Então a tabela produto poderia ser criada assim:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUTO
(
    CODIGO INT PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRICAO VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    ESTOQUE INT,
    VALOR INT,
    CNPJ_FORNECEDOR BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUTO FOREIGN KEY(CNPJ_FORNECEDOR)
    REFERENCES FORNECEDOR (CNPJ)
);
```

Dessa forma evita inserir produtos sem fornecedores, ou pelo menos sem cnpj.

Comment: Valeuu, Bruno!!